# If $A$ is a positive operator, with $\|A\|<1$, then $\|I-A\|<1$, without using spectral theory

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, matrix-calculus, positive-definite

I am working on an exercise for homework that is working towards proving the uniqueness and existence of a square root matrix for any strictly positive operator, without using spectral theory. As a step in my proof, I am trying to show that if we have a strictly positive matrix $A$ with $||A||<1$, then $||I-A|| < 1$. I can tell that intuitively this should be the case, since A is self-adjoint, so its operator norm is equal to its spectral radius, and since the eigenvalues of A are all between 0 and 1, so should be the eigenvalues of $I-A$. However, I want to show directly that $||I-A||<1$, i.e. to show that

$$\sup_{||x||=1} ||I-A||= \sup_{||x||=1} {(x,x)-2(Ax,x)+(Ax,Ax)} < 1.$$

Clearly the first term is 1, and we can use the strict positivity of A to conclude that the second term is negative. However it doesn't appear that there is any simple argument to be made to simplify the expression -- for example we can't just replace $(Ax,Ax)$ with $||A||$, since the supremum of the above sum in the expression is not the sum of the suprema.

Another fact I have tried to utilize is that for A self-adjoint, $$||A|| = \sup_{||x||=1} (Ax,x)$$ but I am not sure how to utilize it.

Could someone please help me with this proof?

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote, but is there any way I can improve the question by making it more clear?

Comment: Yes, sorry i had that assumption in the body but messed up the title. I will edit the title.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I now see why the down vote. Hopefully it's clear after the edit

Comment: I am assuming that A is strictly positive, so it should be invertible

Comment: ok, I will add that as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $A$, and hence $I-A$, is symmetric, then
$$
\|I-A\|=\max_{\|x\|=1}|\langle (I-A)x,x\rangle|
=\max_{\|x\|=1}|\langle x,x\rangle-\langle Ax,x\rangle|.
$$
But $\langle Ax,x\rangle< \langle x,x\rangle$, since $\|A\|<1$. Hence
$$
\|I-A\|
=\max_{\|x\|=1}|\langle x,x\rangle-\langle Ax,x\rangle|
=\max_{\|x\|=1}\big(\langle x,x\rangle-\langle Ax,x\rangle\big)
=1-\min_{\|x\|=1}\langle Ax,x\rangle<1,
$$
since $A$ is positive definite.

Comment: This is perfect, it uses exactly the tools I was hoping to use.